# contar datos de una tabla con parametros de otra

Tags: mysql

tal vez no sea muy claro en la pregunta pero espero dejarlo claro mediante el ejemplo que expongo.

tengo tres tablas de las que necesito sacar una cuenta

tabla A

```
|ciudad_cod |correlativo    |fecha      |estado_cod |detalle   |
|-----------|---------------|-----------|-----------|----------|
|C1011      | 1             |20-01-2018 |E001       |DETALLE 1 | 
|C1011      | 2             |22-03-2018 |E002       |DETALLE 2 | 
|C1012      | 3             |09-05-2018 |E002       |DETALLE 3 |
|C1012      | 4             |01-06-2018 |E002       |DETALLE 4 |
|C1012      | 5             |21-06-2018 |E003       |DETALLE 5 |
|C1013      | 6             |05-08-2018 |E004       |DETALLE 6 |
```

tabla B

```
|ciudad_cod |ciudad     |
|-----------|-----------|
|C1011      |santiago   |
|C1012      |concepcion |
|C1013      |iquique    |
```

tabla C

```
|estado_cod |estado     |
|-----------|-----------|
|E001       |activo     |
|E002       |pendiente  |
|E003       |traspaso   |
|E004       |cerrado    |
```

y como resultado quiero una tabla así

```
|ciudad     |activo |pendiente  |traspaso   |cerrado    |
|-----------|-------|-----------|-----------|-----------|
|santiago   |   1   |   1       |0          |0          |
|concepcion |   0   |   2       |1          |0          |
|iquique    |   0   |   0       |0          |1          |
```

necesito contar los datos de la tabla A pero con los parametros de la tabla B y tabla C

espero que se entienda
gracias

Comment: Bienvenido a Stackoverflow. Por favor muestra lo que has investigado/intentado y cuál es el problema que te da ese código. Gracias.

Comment: La tabla C tiene solo esos estados o puede tener mas?

Comment: la tabla solo tiene esos estados

Answer (score 1):

```
select 
ciudad_cod,
ciudad, 
(select count(1) from tablaA where tablaA.ciudad_cod=tabla b.ciudad_cod and estado_cod='E001') activo,
(select count(1) from tablaA where tablaA.ciudad_cod=tabla b.ciudad_cod and estado_cod='E002') pendiente,
(select count(1) from tablaA where tablaA.ciudad_cod=tabla b.ciudad_cod and estado_cod='E003') traspaso,
(select count(1) from tablaA where tablaA.ciudad_cod=tabla b.ciudad_cod and estado_cod='E004') cerrado
from tabla b
```

Answer (score 1):

a mi me funciona exactamente como quieres tu resultado asi:

```
SELECT
    tablaB.ciudad,
    Count( IF ( tablaa.estado_cod = 'E001', 1, NULL ) ) AS activo,
    Count( IF ( tablaa.estado_cod = 'E002', 1, NULL ) ) AS pendiente,
    Count( IF ( tablaa.estado_cod = 'E003', 1, NULL ) ) AS traspaso,
    Count( IF ( tablaa.estado_cod = 'E004', 1, NULL ) ) AS cerrado 
FROM
    tablaa AS tablaA
    INNER JOIN tablab AS tablaB ON tablaA.ciudad_cod = tablaB.ciudad_cod
GROUP BY tablaB.ciudad
```